# Is this a correct sentence - I was helping him to get the bag off the shelf

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which one is correct?

1. I was helping him to get the bag off the shelf.
2. I was helping him getting the bag off the shelf.
3. None of the above

PS: This is my first post on english stackexchange, any correction around this post will also be appreciated :-)

Comment: Also: "I was helping him get the bag off the shelf." without the *to*. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris is correct, ie. "I was helping him get the bag off the shelf".

Comment: @Kris n SaltySub - Thanks for your input, it cleared my doubt :-) have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Help" can be used with another verb in the infinitive with or without the marker "to." So your first sentence is correct, though omitting the "to" is more common in informal speech.

The second sentence is incorrect, but there is a construction help + indirect object + with/in + present participle/gerund; however, it's usually used for processes more difficult or time-consuming than getting a bag off a shelf.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv226.shtml

Comment: perfect explanation Karl. And thanks for the link, That will clear some of my doubts around complex sentence formation. I have a slight issue of not being able to destruct the sentence in verbs, noun, and adjectives( I have never been able to understand them), but I do alright when it comes to normal (but not advances) sentence formation. Trying to work on my core skills now :-) have a blessed day :-)